# MySQL PHP multiquery

Tags: php, mysql, select, multi-select

I have two tables, Colors and SubProducts

### SubProducts Table

```
SubProductId SubProductColor1 SubProductColor2
1            1                4
2            2                3
```

### Colors Table

```
ColorId ColorName ColorHex ColorCategory
1       color1    303030   0
2       color2    f3f3f3   0
3       color3    dcdcdc   1
4       color4    ededed   1
```

At SubProductColor1 and SubProductColor2 i save the ColorId.

SubProductColor1 is ColorCategory 0.

SubProductColor2 is ColorCategory 1.

I got this :

```
SELECT *
FROM SubProducts
INNER JOIN Colors
ON Colors.ColorId=SubProducts.SubProductColor1
WHERE ProductId='$product_id'
```

but this works for one color only.

I want to get the ColorHex for both colors in a single query.

---

For example, i want this output :

Id = 1

1st Color = 303030

1st Color Name = color1

2nd Color = ededed

2nd Color Name = color4

Id = 2

1st Color = f3f3f3

1st Color Name = color2

2nd Color = dcdcdc

2nd Color Name = color3

---

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try out this..

```
SELECT SubProductID, c1.ColorHex as Color1,c1.ColorName as ColorName1,c2.ColorHex as    Color2,c2.ColorName as ColorName2
    FROM SubProducts INNER JOIN 
    Colors c1 ON c1.ColorId=SubProducts.SubProductColor1 INNER JOIN 
    Colors c2 ON c2.ColorId=SubProducts.SubProductColor2 INNER JOIN 
    WHERE ProductId='$product_id'
```

Comment: how to do this? i think that i need more rep to do it

Answer (score 2):

Remove `WHERE` condition from query

```
SELECT *
FROM SubProducts
INNER JOIN Colors
ON Colors.ColorId=SubProducts.SubProductColor1
```

**Edit**

```
SELECT *
FROM SubProducts,Colors
WHERE (Colors.ColorId = SubProducts.SubProductColor1 OR Colors.ColorId = SubProducts.SubProductColor2)
AND ProductId='$product_id'
GROUP BY Colors.ColorName
```

Comment: I need the where condition, isnt there any way to do this with this condition?

Comment: @zPuls3 In which table `ProductId` is present?

Comment: in two tables, SubProducts and Products. i didnt wrote that because i think that this is not usefull for my question

Comment: @zPuls3 In your posted question there is no such table.

Comment: i know, but i think that there is no need to explain that.

Comment: what should i echo in my while to view those two in a single loop? if i do echo $row['ColorHex'] i can get the first value only.

Comment: yes but it does two rows for every subproduct. ok i know see my fault, i should post the other table too.

Comment: @zPuls3 Use `GROUP BY Colors.ColorName` after `Where`. Also see answer.

Comment: im still getting two rows for reply. i didnt told u that i may have more that one SubProductId's with the same ProductId, so i need the output in a single line

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
SELECT a.SubProductId , a.ColorHex color1, a.ColorName color1name, c.ColorHex color2, c.ColorName color2name 
  from (select * FROM SubProducts 
  JOIN Colors 
    ON Colors.ColorId = SubProducts.SubProductColor1 ) a
  JOIN colors c 
    ON c.ColorId = a.SubProductColor2
 Where SubProductId='$product_id'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT s.subproductid
     , c1.colorhex first_color
     , c1.colorname first_colorname
     , c2.colorhex second_color
     , c2.colorname second_colorname 
  FROM subproducts s 
  JOIN colors c1 
    ON c1.colorid = s.subproductcolor1 
  JOIN colors c2 
    ON c2.colorid = s.subproductcolor2
 ORDER
    BY subproductid;
```

The php loop could look something like this - although obviously you'd be using modern methods instead of the deprecated mysql_ method shown here...

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo "id = ".$row['subproductid']."<br>\n
      1st color = ".$row['first_color']."<br>\n
      1st color name = ".$row['first_colorname']."<br>\n
      2nd color = ".$row['second_color']."<br>\n
      2nd color name = ".$row['second_colorname']."<br>\n
";
}
```

...and note that you're not restricted to 'while'. Other kinds of loop can work just as well (e.g. for($i=0;$i

Comment: and what the while should be like?

Comment: I don't know what you mean.